# Flash message getting erased on redirect

Tags: node.js, connect-flash

I am trying to setup flash message using npm `connect-flash` package.

I read that once I setup the flash message it should be stored in session until next route fires

So inside my post route I have

```
req.flash('success','New user has been added')
console.log(req.flash('success'))
res.redirect("/")
```

This gives me

`['New user has been added']` in my console when my route fires

My redirect page is rendered like:

```
router.get("/", (req, res) => {
    console.log('Home route fired')
    console.log(req.flash('success'))
    res.render("home",{success:req.flash('success'));
})
```

This gives me

```
Home route fired
[]
```

So the `req.flash('success')` is suddenly an empty array. No other routes fires between the req.flash setup and the redirect page render. How can the `req.flash('success')` be empty?

Comment: The reason is that calling `req.flash('success')` will return the message you previosly added by calling `req.flash('success','New user has been added')` and also delete that message from flash so calling `req.flash('success')` again will return an empty array.  To debug it and prevent deletion you can try `console.log(req.flash.session.flash);` it should return an object like `{ success: [ array of messages] }`

Comment: You were right. Not sure why this happens

Comment: Well once you get the message using `req.flash('success')` you no longer need it to be stored anywhere so flash is clever enough to delete it for you. It makes perfect sense to me.